# Java 2-d array I/O

Tags: java, arrays

Ive had some problems writing out my stored data from my array to a text file. 
I've managed to get some kind of data in the file but I've had problems understanding what it really is (is it correct?). The thing is, the file is about 4Mb and when I try to open it - it doesn't open because the computer is just trying to load it. So I then use the "cat gedit filename" command in the terminal (yes I use linux) and I see lots of squares with digits in each square being printed out, almost looks like bits because I see lots of zeros and ones. But also I'm very aware that my array contains lots of zeros and ones which makes it hard to see if it's even the contents of the array.
See the code below.

However, regarding the other code in the file is solving a problem from Project Euler, but I'm going to use the data for something else myself so I want to store it all in an array then save it to a separate file. Solving the problem is fine it works out well, but - my "write-to-file" (see method "write") doesn't work - or it does work but I'm not able to understand the contents of the file.

The file should contain lots of zeros and ones, some higher (highest value in the array is 71), and the array is a square matrix of size 2000x2000.
I've tried printing out the contents of the array separately to debug and see if it works so far - and it does.

```
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;


    public class Euler27_MATLAB {

        public static boolean isPrime(int n){
            if(n<2 || (n>2 && n%2==0)){
                return false;
            }else if(n==2){
                return true;
            }else{
                for(int i=3; i<=Math.sqrt(n); i=i+2){
                    if(n%i==0){
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }       
        }
                   //THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP

        public static void write (String filename, int[][]x) throws IOException{
              BufferedWriter outputWriter = null;
              outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
              for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                for(int j=0; j<x.length; j++){ //array is square
                    outputWriter.write((x[i][j]));
                }
                outputWriter.newLine();
              }
              outputWriter.flush();  
              //outputWriter.close();  
            }
        public static void main(String[] args){
            int tmp=0; int A = 0; int B = 0; int limit = 1000;
            int nbr = 0;
            int [][]array = new int[limit*2+1][limit*2+1];
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for(int a=-limit; a<=limit; a++){ //2 if only odd nbrs
                for(int b=-limit; b<=limit; b++){   
                    while(isPrime(nbr*nbr+a*nbr+b)){ //n^2+an+b
                        nbr++;
                    }
                     array[a+limit][b+limit]=nbr;

                    if(nbr>tmp){    //store the values for later out-print
                        tmp = nbr; A=a; B=b;
                    }
                    nbr=0;
                }
            }
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            System.out.println("The product a*b is: " + A*B + "\nwith a=" + A +
                    " and b=" + B + " with limit " + limit +".");
             System.out.println("Formula generated " + tmp + " primes.");
            System.out.println("Time: " + time + " ms.");

                //FOR THE ARRAY ----------------------------------------------
            try{
                write("/home/robin/workspace/ProjectEuler/src/pe27",array); 
            }catch(E`enter code here`xception e){
                System.out.println("Failure");
            }
        }
    }
```

ive tried codes that i found on google and couldnt get those to work either.

Jill

Comment: Not related but `cat gedit filename` makes no sense. You mean `cat filename`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
outputWriter.write((x[i][j]));
```

You're writing an `int` to a file. An integer is 4 bytes that make up a value. The file contains exactly what you're writing to it; 4 bytes for every `int`. That, however, does not represent anything remotely human readable.

By your description of trying to view this file, I'm assuming you're attempting to write human readable *text* to this file in which case you would need to convert the `int` to a `String` that represents that integer value.

```
outputWriter.write(String.valueOf(x[i][j]));
```

**Edit to expand:**

Files contain bytes. To be human readable, those bytes have to be mapped to a character set  (which is most likely going to be UTF-8 on your system by default).

Right now, lets say `x[0][0]` were to contain the value `1` That means if you write that value to a file as an `int` the following 4 bytes are written to the file: `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001`

When you attempt to open the file with a text editor or view it with `cat`, those programs attempt to map those bytes to a human readable character set ... and fail miserably. That's why you're seeing "lots of squares with digits in each square being printed out"

In UTF-8 the character "1" maps to a single byte holding the value `49`. Writing that character to a file means a single byte is written to the file: `00110001`

That is something programs that show human readable text can display by mapping it to UTF-8

Answer (score -2):

The data in the file is correct. Java serializes data when storing to files, and this is a binary format, not text. This is faster to load afterwards. It is not meant to be human-readable.

If you want human-readable output, you should consider XML, YAML or other text-based formats.

Comment: I didn't downvote but ... there's no objects involved here, and no need for a ridiculous markup language to print some numbers to a file.

Comment: Correct about objects. About the ridiculous markup language, please note: *"or other text-based formats"*